# Как скрыть чужие окна?

Tags: c++

Работаю с чужим окном из своей программы. Как сделать так, чтобы все окна, которые открывает чужое (главное) окно сразу были скрытыми ?
Сейчас я открываю другие окна, нахожу их HWND и скрываю. Из-за этого окна появляются на мгновенье, чего не хотелось бы.
Спасибо!

Comment: У меня нет исходного кода чужой программы

Comment: @Andrey: Чистого решения нет. Программа должна сотрудничать, иначе у вас будет гонка вооружени[й](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253/).

Comment: Каким образом ? Чтобы выполнить CreateWindow я должен знать хендл окна . А этот хендл создается чужой программой .

Comment: Ну создайте stub вместо user32.dll, подмените там CreateWindow на вашу имплементацию, напишите собственный загрузчик процесса, и подставьте вашу dll вместо user32. Хотите странного — придётся постараться.

Comment: Нет ли какого-нибудь метода , который сделает так, чтобы все дочерние окна создавались скрытыми? Либо может можно как-то перехватывать события создания окон из родительского окна ?

Comment: В каком смысле «дочернее» окно? Это окно другого процесса.

Comment: Дочернее окно чужой проги. Я запускаю чужую прогу, эмитирую нажатие кнопки в ней. Он в ответ выводит диалог в новом окне. Я хочу чтобы этот диалог был скрыт.

Comment: В общем случае окна никак не наследуют никакие свойства других окон программы. Поэтому то, что вы просите, просто так не сделать. Нужно искать каждое окно и отдельно его скрывать.

Comment: Может как-то можно заставить виндовс открывать все окна после запуска проги в скрытом состоянии ?

Comment: Да и открытие окна должно ведь происходить после какого-то события ? Не так ли ?

Comment: Да, ловите `WM_NCCREATE` (там, кстати, есть возможность не только изменять оконные стили, но и отменить создание окна вообще).

Comment: Спасибо ! Осталось только перехватить это событие . Может кто знает, как это сделать ?